# QLineEdit::textEdited() equivalent in QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtextedit, qlineedit

In `QLineEdit`, there is a `textEdit()` signal, which only emits if the user changes the text, but not when you call `setText()`,

So what's the equivalent in `QTextEdit`? I only see a `textChanged()` signal, and the documentation states it is emitted whenever the text document changes.

**EDIT**

I want to implement an auto-save feature, with a QTimer of course,

So when you start editing the document, the timer starts, and when timed out, I save the text inside the widget.

Comment: I don't think there's a signal for that. What scenario is this for?

Answer (score 12):

You can block signals of the `QTextEdit` widget whenever you insert/modify the contents yourself, and then release the block when you're done. By doing that the signal will only be emitted when the user makes changes to the contents.

```
bool QObject::blockSignals(bool block)
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked for my mentor's code and he solved the problem this way:

1. Install event filter for `QTextEdit` object (`this` is pointer to mEdit holder, which is QWidget)

> ```
> mEdit->installEventFilter(this);
> ```

2. Override `QObject::eventFilter` method in class, which contains `QTextEdit` object (remember, it's `QWidget` inheritor)

> ```
> //override
> bool CustomEditWidget::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
> {
>     if(watched == mEdit && event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut){
>         changeValue(mEdit->toPlainText());
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

The rest you can see in the documentation, there are examples: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter